# Magento need to install SUPEE-8167 anyway?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-ipn, patch

regarding the patch for PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN), i'm not using Paypal IPN, infact in my account IPN has not configured, so i would like to ask you, do i have to install the pacth anyway?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install super 8167 is for security purpose in future may be you  Need paypal to your website so i suggest you can install.